# “kill on the sawdust” meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does “kill on the sawdust” mean here?

‘I thought killing was easy for you,’ said Laurent. His voice was rather quiet. ‘I thought you did it without thinking.’

‘I’m a soldier,’ said Damen, ‘and I have been for a long time. I’ve killed on the sawdust. I’ve killed in battle. Is that what you mean by easy?’

-Captive Prince, Volume 2 by C. S. Pacat

Answer (score 2):

Sawdust is used in many places at absorb spilt liquids such as blood, vomit and urine in butchers shops, abattoirs, circuses etc.

The former soldier has killed both on the battlefield and states "I have killed on the sawdust" I would interpret this to mean he has killed in an arena as entertainment as a form of gladiator, not having read the book. The floor of the arena would be covered with sawdust to absorb the blood etc. split by the dead.

It occurs to me know it could also mean he has killed  on the training room floor, in some extremely violent warrior societies occasionally killing real people was part of the gaining. Spartans would have to kill a helot slave before they were considered real soldiers for example. Sawdust would act as an absorbant there as well.